# Deploy Vue.js build with Gitlab CI

Tags: vue.js, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This is my gitlab pipeline. The Vue.js artifacts are build on the runner. How can I deploy the to my testserver? FYI: `Fab pull` does a `git pull` on the repo.

```
deploy_staging:
  image: python:3.6
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash -
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install -y curl git gnupg nodejs
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - |
      cat >~/.ssh/config <<EOF
      Host testserver
          ForwardAgent yes
          HostName dev.testserver.ts
          User testuser
      EOF
    - cat ~/.ssh/config
  script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - npm install
    - npm run production
    - fab pull
```

Comment: Do you want to copy build artifacts (e.g `dist` folder) from runner to your `testserver`??

Comment: Yes Amir, that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to copy files from GitLab runner into your server, This will be possible using `scp` command.
For example:

```
⋮
 script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - npm install
    - npm run production
    - scp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /PATH/TO/BUILD_ARTIFACTS testserver:~/PATH/TO/DESTINATION
    - fab pull
```

`UserKnownHostsFile` and `StrictHostKeyChecking` are SSH options that prevent error `Host key verification failed`. So they should be used with `scp` command in your case.
Also, destination path of artifact files must be started from `testuser`'s home directory (Tilde character `~`). Otherwise you may face `Permission denied` error.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had almost the same code, but didn't know about the `UserKnownHostsFile` and `StrictHostKeyChecking` options.